# How to filter rooms based on user's input as room_capacity , check_in_date and check_out date in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

Here is my input form which takes user's input as room_capcity , check_in_date and check_out_date :

**HTML Page**

```
<!-- Filter form -->
  <form
  action="{% url 'Rooms:show_filtered_rooms' %}"
  method="POST"
  class="flex flex-row justify-center my-8 mx-10 space-x-4"
>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="flex flex-col">
      <label for="room_capacity" class="text-xl font-semibold">Room Capacity</label>
      <select
          name="room_capacity"
          id="room_capacity"
          class="w-48 h-10 border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-md"
      >
          <option value="" hidden>Select Room Capacity</option>
          <option value="single">Single</option>
          <option value="double">Double</option>
          <option value="triple">Triple</option>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-col">
      <label for="check_in_date" class="text-xl font-semibold">Check In Date</label>
      <input
          type="date"
          name="check_in_date"
          id="check_in_date"
          class="w-48 h-10 border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-md"
      />
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-col">
      <label for="check_out_date" class="text-xl font-semibold">Check Out Date</label>
      <input
          type="date"
          name="check_out_date"
          id="check_out_date"
          class="w-48 h-10 border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-md"
      />
  </div>

  
  <button
      type="submit"
      class="px-1 py-1 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md hover:bg-blue-600"
  >
      Apply Filters
  </button>
</form>

<!-- Filter form ends -->
```

Here is my logic in view.py file:

```
def  showFilteredRooms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        room_capacity = request.POST.get('room_capacity')
        check_in_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('check_in_date'), '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        check_out_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('check_out_date'), '%Y-%m-      %d').date()
 
        print(room_capacity)
        print(check_in_date)
        print(check_out_date)
        
        

        # Step 1: Get booked rooms with the specified capacity and overlapping date range
        booked_rooms = Booking.objects.filter(
        capacity=room_capacity,
        checkInDate__lte=check_out_date,
        checkOutDate__gte=check_in_date ).values_list('roomNo', flat=True)
       
 
        
        # Step 2: Get available rooms with the specified capacity
        available_rooms = Room.objects.filter(
            capacity=room_capacity
        ).exclude(roomNo__in=booked_rooms)
       
        print(available_rooms)

        context = {
            'available_rooms': available_rooms,
            'filter_applied': True,  # Set this flag to indicate filter applied
        }

        return render(request, 'show_all_rooms.html', context)
```

Here is my Booking model in Booking app;

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(userAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    roomNo = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    guestName = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")
    roomType = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="General")
    capacity = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="Single")
    bookingDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    checkInDate = models.DateField()
    checkOutDate = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.roomNo) + " " + str(self.guestName)
```

I think the logic is correct but there is some issue in the code ,like user's input and date , as its not showing the exact room after applying filter.
Its showing blank rooms .